# Gmail imap, smtp with oauth 2.0 in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, gmail-imap

I am new to ROR. Just finished [learn by examples](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) by Michael Hurtle.

I think the best way to learn a new language is to develop something out of it.

So, I want to port my Asp.net app in ROR.

My app uses a gmail's imap/stmp to send/receive emails. I use [XOAUTH 2.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/xoauth2_protocol) for authentication.

I googled for the same in ROR and found [gmail](https://github.com/nu7hatch/gmail) gem. It has great features but it does not support 2.0. It supports until 1.0.

I am newbie and cannot change this gem to support 2.0

Can somebody provide a blog link / gem so that I can use gmail smtp/imap in rails with XOAUTH 2.0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using [gmail_xoauth](https://github.com/nfo/gmail_xoauth) gem.

It looks promising. My thought that it doesnt have any docs was wrong.

It uses the [Net::SMTP](http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/net/smtp/rdoc/classes/Net/SMTP.html) library of ruby to send emails. ( I am new to ROR , so wasnt aware of this)

I am able to send an email successfully by using just my `email` and `access_token` i.e. XOAUTH2

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for OAuth authentication, you should checkout [this gem](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth).

If all you need is to send emails through gmail via smtp you can do it only with [action mailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#example-action-mailer-configuration). I've beed using this for some time and it works.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, GMail IMAP doesn't support OAuth2, only OAuth. You can use gmail_xoauth gem.

Comment: gmail supports Oauth 2.0 . My asp.net based app is using it. gmail_xoauth gem supports it but I couldnt find any docs for how to use this gem.

Comment: IMAP doesn't support OAuth2, AFAIK. If you have other information, please paste a link. Oh, I see. This is something new. Cool.